# Regular expression for find and replace string

Tags: jquery, regex

In my HTML page this `img` `src` and `id` (`img src="test/image1" id="textEditor1"`) is used in so many places I want a regular expression to replace image source (`test/image1`) to `http://www.himanihotels.in/assets/images/c/db2d2b9d-8f35-44cf-9d62-4a15fb67fe2a.jpg` and replace all `id` (id's can be `textEditor1` to `textEditor100`) with blank space?

```
<div style="background-color:yellow">
    <p>Need help?</p>
    <img src="test/image1" id="textEditor1" />
</div>
```

Comment: It would be much better to amend the actual source, instead of using JS as a crutch to fix glaring errors.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need a regex for the first find/replace. (Assuming you are using the same image everywhere. If you are not replacing with the same image, then what you ask is impossible with regex alone.)

For the second, just replace `id="textEditor\d+"\s*` with an empty string.